# get the return value from async function without calling it again

Tags: javascript, async-await

Here is the code:

```
const onStartRecord = async() => {
  try {
    const path = Platform.select({
      ios: `file:///audio/${filenameGenerator}.m4a`,
      android: `file:///audio/${filenameGenerator}.mp4`,
    });
    const audioSet: AudioSet = {
      AudioEncoderAndroid: AudioEncoderAndroidType.AAC,
      AudioSourceAndroid: AudioSourceAndroidType.MIC,
      AVEncoderAudioQualityKeyIOS: AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType.high,
      AVNumberOfChannelsKeyIOS: 2,
      AVFormatIDKeyIOS: AVEncodingOption.aac,
    };
    console.log('audioSet', audioSet);
    const uri = await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder(path, audioSet);
    audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener((e: any) => {
      setAudioProp(audioProp => {
        return { ...audioProp,
          recordSecs: e.current_position,
          recordTime: audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.current_position)),
        }
      });

    });

    console.log(`uri: ${uri}`);
    return uri
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
};

const audioPath = async() => {
  const result = await onStartRecord();
  return result;
}

const onSubmit = async() => {
  const audiopath = await audioPath();
  console.log("this is the audiopath", audiopath)
}
};
```

I can get what I want when I trigger the onSubmit function, but the problem is, it also trigger the onStartRecord function again which will cause error in my case, I just want to get the uri generated when the onStartRecord resolved, but I don't want to trigger it again, so what can I do if I need to use the onSubmit function and get the value from onStartRecord? thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning `uri`, `onStartRecord` should assign it to a global variable.

Then `audioPath()` can return that variable.

```
let savedAudioPath;

const onStartRecord = async() => {
  try {
    const path = Platform.select({
      ios: `file:///audio/${filenameGenerator}.m4a`,
      android: `file:///audio/${filenameGenerator}.mp4`,
    });
    const audioSet: AudioSet = {
      AudioEncoderAndroid: AudioEncoderAndroidType.AAC,
      AudioSourceAndroid: AudioSourceAndroidType.MIC,
      AVEncoderAudioQualityKeyIOS: AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType.high,
      AVNumberOfChannelsKeyIOS: 2,
      AVFormatIDKeyIOS: AVEncodingOption.aac,
    };
    console.log('audioSet', audioSet);
    const uri = await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder(path, audioSet);
    audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener((e: any) => {
      setAudioProp(audioProp => {
        return { ...audioProp,
          recordSecs: e.current_position,
          recordTime: audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.current_position)),
        }
      });

    });

    console.log(`uri: ${uri}`);
    savedAudioPath = uri;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
};

const audioPath = async () => savedAudioPath;
```

Comment: Thx Barmar, I tried your code, but still, it trigger the onStartRercord again which will return something not I want

Comment: I don't think that should happen unless you call it again before the first call has returned.

Comment: because when I play the audio file, it is not what I record in the first press(I mean the first time I trigger the onStartRecord), but the file recorded the sound after I press the onSubmit button

Comment: Do you see the log messages from `onStartRecord()` the second time?

Comment: any help,plzzzzz~~

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't work. Are you sure you have the variable declaration outside the function?

Comment: I added some console logs, which messages do you see now?

Comment: this one:Saved startRecordResult

Comment: Every time you click it says that?

Comment: You're not reloading the page, are you? Variables get reset whenever the page is reloaded.

Comment: because the onSubmit trigger the audioPath and the audioPath trigger the onStartRecord function to execute, but i just want to "print" the return uri from onStartRecord

Comment: I didn't reload the page

Comment: Then I really don't understand what's happening. The code is clear, isn't it? The first time you call `audioPath` it assigns the variable. The next time it should skip the call to `onStartRecord` because the variable is already assigned.

Comment: Something must be clearing the variable, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Is this code inside another function? Every time you call that other function, you'll get new variables. The `startRecordResult` variable needs to be really global.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear enough, 1.i have a button to trigger the onStartRecord function and the app start recording, when I finished recording, I will press a StopRecord function, and then, I will press the onSubmit function to save the audio file to backend,so it order to get the path, I make the audioPath function to try to get the path from onStartRecord function.

Comment: I put the let startRecordResult outside my functional component, but the log is the same

Comment: Now I understand, I thought you were always calling `onStartRecord` from `audioPath`. I've revised my answer.

Comment: thx Barmar for your help, but this time the console.log("this is the audiopath", audiopath) undefined for the audiopath

Comment: finally solved it , thx Barmar, I  add the return  savedAudioPath in the   onStartRecord, now it works!!!!